# mina writefuture returns written=true despite failing

Tags: java, tcp, apache-mina

This is the code

```
                WriteFuture writeFuture = session.write(message);
                writeFuture.addListener(this);
                writeFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
                sentMessage = writeFuture.isWritten();
```

Before sending a message, I disconnect the server from the network (pull cable) so that the message cannot possibly be sent. However, sentMessage will return true anyway. On wiresharks output you can see three TCP Retransmissions (and obviously no acks). After a few more messages (not the same message as the first) it will realize the link is down and return false.

I thought this isWritten() told you if the packet was successfully sent but apparently this is not so. How do I know if the packet has arrived? I tried mina version 2.0.7 and 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The write success is declared when the message is pushed to the  kernel.
This is how socket works you can't know when the TCP message is sent or acked